# Magneto displaying tax but taking tax off the tax :S

Tags: magento2.3, tax, tax-calculation

So I have tax set up at 20%. The actual rate it’s taking off is about 14%

I noticed that the figure it’s showing is actually the correct Tax figure **minus** the tax.

Which is crazy.

Here’s what it’s doing.

Subtotal : £100
Tax : 16.68 (which is 20 - 20%)
Total without tax : 83.32

It’s deducting tax from the tax figure before it displays it.

I can’t imagine this would be a setting, who would ever want to do this.

I have all the setup correct, it’s applying the correct rule, it’s just deducting tax from the tax figure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Just a further note, the tax config is set to recognise that prices entered by admin are including tax

Answer (score 0):

20% of 83.32 is 16.68 so the tax calculation is correct.

Subtotal will have :
product cost plus tax on product.

When you state prices inclusive tax then it will do a reverse calculation and calculate tax amount and product price.

parameters :

1. Product price
2. Tax percentage.
3. Is product price inclusive or exclusive tax.

tax amount =(100/(100 + tax rate ))*product price)